# Tensorflow - How to read the prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a problem.
For a school project, I created a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) where I wanted to predict if the stock price will rise or fall. I also have some data from a CSV file. Training went fine, so I was ready to predict some tests. From the RNN I get some results because it has multiple predictions over a period of a week.
Here is my code:

```
import io
import requests
import os
import time
import random

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn import preprocessing
from collections import deque

#Constant Variables
SEQ_LEN = 30
FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT = 3
RATIO_TO_PREDICT = "LTC-USD"
BATCH_SIZE = 64
NAME = str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "-" + str(SEQ_LEN) + "-SEQ-" + str(FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT) + "-PRED-" + str(int(time.time()))
ACTIONS = ["Sell", "Buy"]

def classify(current, future):
    if float(future) > float(current):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

def preprocess_df(df):
    df = df.drop('future', 1)

    for col in df.columns:
        if col != "target":
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change()
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            #df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)

    df.dropna(inplace=True)

    sequential_data = []
    prev_days = deque(maxlen=SEQ_LEN)



    for i in df.values:
        prev_days.append([n for n in i[:-1]])
        if len(prev_days) == SEQ_LEN:
            sequential_data.append([np.array(prev_days), i[-1]])

    buys = []
    sells = []

    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        if target == 0:
            sells.append([seq, target])
        elif target == 1:
            buys.append([seq, target])


    random.shuffle(buys)
    random.shuffle(sells)

    lower = min(len(buys), len(sells))


    buys = buys[:lower]
    sells = sells[:lower]


    sequential_data = buys+sells

    x = []
    y = []

    for seq, target in sequential_data:
        x.append(seq)
        y.append(target)

    return np.array(x), y




main_df = pd.DataFrame()

ratios = ["BTC-USD", "LTC-USD", "ETH-USD"]
for ratio in ratios:


    url="https://www.test.nl/get_csv_data_onscreen.php?method=test&ratio=" + str(ratio)
    dataset = requests.get(url, verify=False).content
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(dataset.decode('utf-8')), names=["time", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume", "rsi14", "ma5", "ema5", "ema12", "ema20", "macd", "signal"])

    df.rename(columns={"close": str(ratio)+"_close", "volume": str(ratio) + "_volume", "rsi14": str(ratio) + "_rsi14", "ma5": str(ratio) + "_ma5", "ema5": str(ratio) + "_ema5", "ema12": str(ratio) + "_ema12", "ema20": str(ratio) + "_ema20", "macd": str(ratio) + "_macd", "signal": str(ratio) + "_signal"}, inplace=True)

    df.set_index("time", inplace=True)
    df = df[[str(ratio) + "_close", str(ratio) + "_volume", str(ratio) + "_rsi14", str(ratio) + "_ma5", str(ratio) + "_ema5", str(ratio) + "_ema12", str(ratio) + "_ema20", str(ratio) + "_macd", str(ratio) + "_signal"]]

    if len(main_df) == 0:
        main_df = df
    else:
        main_df = main_df.join(df)


main_df['future'] = main_df[str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "_close"].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT)
main_df['target'] = list(map(classify, main_df[str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "_close"], main_df["future"]))
#print(main_df[[str(RATIO_TO_PREDICT) + "_close", "future", "target"]].head(10))


times = sorted(main_df.index.values)
last_5pct = times[-int(0.05*len(times))]

validation_main_df = main_df[(main_df.index >= last_5pct)]
main_df = main_df[(main_df.index < last_5pct)]

test_x, test_y = preprocess_df(main_df)
validation_x, validation_y = preprocess_df(validation_main_df)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("models\Crypto_Model_0.6337.h5")

predictions = model.predict(test_x)
print(predictions)
print(ACTIONS[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

So when I print the predictions I get a list of numbers arround 0 and 1. Here is a short version of the result:

```
[[ 0.61009574]
 [ 0.5243717 ]
 [ 0.56290686]
 [ 0.49165   ]
 [ 0.50527   ]
 [ 0.77428705]
 [ 0.62151164]
 [ 0.55098933]
 [ 0.45642132]
 [ 0.61239064]
 [ 0.69220203]
 [ 0.3707057 ]
 [ 0.5335519 ]
 [ 0.43078205]
 [ 0.57520276]
 [ 0.46626005]
 [ 0.37625414]
 [ 0.56013215]]
```

But what is the latest datapoint. For example, here is a part of the list I upload:

```
1535782500,63.41,63.63,63.47,63.52,83505,55.104896,63.574000,63.586200,63.61220000,63.454000,0.31080000,0.44500684
1535783400,63.44,63.74,63.52,63.62,95980,56.921744,63.578000,63.597500,63.61340000,63.469800,0.28840000,0.41370000
1535784300,63.62,63.86,63.64,63.81,71996,60.216065,63.616000,63.668300,63.64360000,63.502200,0.28270000,0.38750000
1535785200,63.71,64.00,63.83,63.82,101652,60.387764,63.644000,63.718900,63.67070000,63.532500,0.27580000,0.36520000
1535786100,63.64,63.87,63.82,63.84,78686,60.752590,63.722000,63.759300,63.69670000,63.561800,0.26880000,0.34590000
1535787000,63.76,63.88,63.84,63.84,82486,60.752590,63.786000,63.786200,63.71870000,63.588300,0.26030000,0.32880000
1535787900,63.70,63.89,63.84,63.72,71654,57.093572,63.806000,63.764100,63.71890000,63.600800,0.24110000,0.31130000
1535788800,63.69,63.87,63.73,63.76,88931,58.001593,63.796000,63.762700,63.72520000,63.616000,0.22650000,0.29430000
1535789700,63.71,63.86,63.79,63.82,87103,59.389894,63.796000,63.781800,63.73980000,63.635400,0.21730000,0.27890000
1535790600,63.76,63.97,63.77,63.89,102919,61.009256,63.806000,63.817900,63.76290000,63.659600,0.21320000,0.26580000
```

I input 1 week of data of 15 minutes, So that is 672 rows. So just to be clear....

Is the last value of predictions the prediction of the last row from the csv file?

Comment: Does anyone else know the awnser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you shuffling the sequential time data? The date/time index should be in each row and tell you what day it is predicting. Shuffling sequential data isn't heavily recommended for training RNNs or LSTMs. It also appears like you are trying to apply reinforcement learning which I would always recommend avoiding for training, you can get a few lucky actions and the model will just remember the data points, not generalize an algorithm.

Comment: `ACTIONS = ["Sell", "Buy"]` This variable makes me think that. What is the purpose of the actions? To record the potential for a backtesting? You should validate your model with some more statistical methods before action based methods.

Comment: No thats for the last part that I didn't add: `print(ACTIONS[int(prediction[0][0])])`. So if the price will be higher, its a Buy, else it's a Sell

Comment: However, If I print the predicitions, I can't print the time, so I don't know which is the last prediction! Can you help me with that?

Comment: Remove this line `random.shuffle(sequential_data)` to actually get sequential training on the series. Isn't the first column in your output data the date of the prediction?